# Add widget to activity

Tags: android, widget

hey, 
I've developped a car dock application.
I can add shortcuts in my activity but how can I add a system widget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) class in your application. See a tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part1) and make sure you follow the design [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html).